# where to place firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() in Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I need to check whether the user logged in with Firebase. For this we use

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
       // example
       this.user = user
       })
```

We are also using Vue.js so I was wondering whether it should be implemented as a watcher, method or even a computed property. And of course how that would be implemented.

Comment: You might be better off using the official integration: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `created ()` method of the `main.js` file

Comment: Thanks, but in Node environment, should it be placed in the `created ()` of the root Vue instance, or the component?

Answer (score 3):

In cases I am not using Vuex, I am using the FBase this way:

```
<script>
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

return default {
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: '',
    fb: null,
    fbConf: {
      apiKey: 'your API key',
      authDomain: '<your-domain>.firebaseapp.com'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logIn (user) {
      this.user = user.uid
    },
  },
  created () {
    this.fb = firebase
    this.fb.initializeApp(this.fbConf)
    this.fb.auth().signInAnonymously()
    this.fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.logIn)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: and what if you do use Vuex ?