# How to update vue app data when a global variable changes

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

```
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

// user signs in code...

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            username: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getUserName() {
            this.username = auth.currentUser.displayName
       },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUserName()
    }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

The code above does not work because when the vue app is mounted the user is not yet signed in. The user is therefore null. However at a later time when the user does sign in, the code does not update. I wish to have a way to watch on changes on the user state so as to update the local vue variable.

Comment: You cannot do this in general. As for firebase, there's a plenty of existing posts on the subject. You need to use onauthstatechanged . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535737/where-to-place-firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-in-vuejs